# How to change componentWillUpdate to getSnapshotBeforeUpdate

Tags: reactjs

I'm updating the application with React 15 to React 16, and I have the warning in the console about

> Warning: componentWillUpdate has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.

This is how it looks like in the code:

```js
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (nextState.isOpen === this.state.isOpen) return;

        if (nextState.isOpen) this.showSlider();
        else this.hideSlider();
    }
```

How I can rewrite it to the new life cycle method `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`?

I tried the next way:

```js
getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (nextState.isOpen) return this.showSlider();
        return this.hideSlider();
    }
```

But it's does not seems right and does not work.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: you don't need it at all ... render slider considtionally ... JSX: `{this.state.isOpen && <Slider />}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params of `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` are for the prev props and states, not the next props and states. So the code should be like the following one:

```
getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.isOpen === this.state.isOpen) return;

  if (this.state.isOpen) this.showSlider();
  else this.hideSlider();
}
```

Comment: this is works, but I got an error in console: ```Collapsible.getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(): A snapshot value (or null) must be returned. You have returned undefined. ```

Comment: maybe in this line `if (prevState.isOpen === this.state.isOpen) return;` , you returned nothing. so try to use `return null;`